# Is loosing TextField text due to app focus out an expected behaviour?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I've created the simplest app: it's just a default project with added TextController and TextField. Nothing more. Here is a code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(controller: _controller,),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

The actions I'm doing: tap on the text field, enter several symbols from the onscreen keyboard without committing, then press the switch app button. After that, I see the list of running apps with the current flutter app with the entered text. Then I click on the flutter app and entered text disappears.

I'm expecting that it's wrong behaviour. The text should not disappear.
Am I wrong? Or I have missed something? I'm new to flutter and everything here is very strange and it conflicts with practically all my previous experience.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47628#issuecomment-578589462

Comment: So it looks like a bug? Since last December...

Comment: That's what it looks like, it is written that it is a synchronization problem between the framework and host platform (android) that is doing this

Comment: I see, thank you. Will try a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's expected because when you enter your widget it's state gets build, and you declared the variable in state class, so every time the state is build the `_controller` will be assigned to a new instance of `TextEditingController` and the previous instance of `TextEditingController`(which had your value inside of it) will be available for garbage collection.

Comment: I've tried adding print statements in several places: `_MyHomePageState` constructor, `_MyHomePageState.build` and custom text controller constructor. Neither of the statements has printed anything to the console during the actions (on app startup everything has been printed out as expected).

Comment: i am not sure i follow you, what do you mean that it got printed on app start up but not in the `_MyHomePageState` Widget?

Comment: Here is the code https://gist.github.com/ChessMax/370a553d7a8e214a39ffb954df1ebc78. When the app starts I see: MyController; _MyHomePageState; MyBuild in the console as expected. But when I'm doing actions described in the question I don't see any messages in the console. So, no new `TextEditingController` is created during this time.

Comment: I agree with the comments it look like a bug.